# WooCommerce: Display stock quantity for a given product ID on normal Pages or Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product-quantity

I am trying to display the product quantity for a given product ID outside WoCommerce pages, in the normal WordPress Pages or Posts.

I assume you paste some code into functions.php then have a snippet you put in the post or page.
 
I'm really struggling here and only half-baked answers I've found so far where none of them work for me...

How do I echo the stock quantity of a WooCommerce product ID on a normal Wordpress page or post?

Comment: You could try searching/asking here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way is to make a custom shortcode function, that is going to output the product quantity for a given product ID.

The code for this shortcode function:

```
if( !function_exists('show_specific_product_quantity') ) {

    function show_specific_product_quantity( $atts ) {

        // Shortcode Attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'id' => '', // Product ID argument
            ),
            $atts,
            'product_qty'
        );

        if( empty($atts['id'])) return;

        $stock_quantity = 0;

        $product_obj = wc_get_product( intval( $atts['id'] ) );
        $stock_quantity = $product_obj->get_stock_quantity();

        if( $stock_quantity > 0 ) return $stock_quantity;

    }

    add_shortcode( 'product_qty', 'show_specific_product_quantity' );

}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

---

**USAGE**

> The shortcode works with an **`ID`** argument (the targeted product ID).

1) In a WordPress Page or Post content, just paste this shortcode in the text editor to display the stock quantity for a given product ID (Here the ID is **`37`**):

```
[product_qty id="37"]
```

2 In any PHP code (example):

```
echo '<p>Product quantity is: ' . do_shortcode( '[product_qty id="37"]' ) .'</p><br>';
```

3 In an HTML/PHP page (example):

```html
<p>Product quantity is: <?php echo do_shortcode( '[product_qty id="37"]' ); ?></p>
```

> **Similar:** [Display custom stock quantity conditionally via shortcode on Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856097/display-custom-stock-quantity-conditionally-via-shortcode-on-woocommerce/53856519#53856519)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I've been looking for. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec, is there a posibility to show a message "more than X" if there are more than X products? It should show 1, 2, 3, 4... X, and if bigger than X, it shouldn't show the exact quantity. Can it be done?

Comment: It's still working perfectly for me one and a year after :)