# Display custom stock quantity conditionally via shortcode on Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, shortcode, stock

I'm using [WooCommerce: Display stock quantity for a given product ID on normal Pages or Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686282/woocommerce-display-stock-quantity-for-a-given-product-id-on-normal-pages-or-po/44689062#44689062) amazing answer code that works to display the product quantity for a WooCommerce product in any page or post via a shortcode.

I would like to only display the exact quantity up to 5 products in stock and have "More than 5" for any quantity of 6 or more.

Can it be done by modifying this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
if( !function_exists('show_specific_product_quantity') ) {

    function show_specific_product_quantity( $atts ) {

        // Shortcode Attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'id' => '', // Product ID argument
            ),
            $atts,
            'product_qty'
        );

        if( empty($atts['id'])) return;

        $stock_quantity = 0;

        $product_obj = wc_get_product( intval( $atts['id'] ) );
        $stock_quantity = $product_obj->get_stock_quantity();

        if( $stock_quantity > 0 && $stock_quantity <= 5 ) 
            return $stock_quantity;
        elseif( $stock_quantity > 5 ) 
            return __("More than 5", "woocommerce");

    }
    add_shortcode( 'product_qty', 'show_specific_product_quantity' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

---

**Addition - Display Zero Stock number too:**

Just change the following code line:

```
if( $stock_quantity > 0 && $stock_quantity <= 5 )
```

to:

```
if( $stock_quantity >= 0 && $stock_quantity <= 5 )
```

Now zero stock will be displayed too…

---

Original answer: [WooCommerce: Display stock quantity for a given product ID on normal Pages or Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686282/woocommerce-display-stock-quantity-for-a-given-product-id-on-normal-pages-or-po/44689062#44689062)

Answer (score -2):

You could try adding to this line

```
if( $stock_quantity > 0 ) return $stock_quantity;
```

try:

```
$overQty = "More than 5";

if( $stock_quantity > 5 ){ return $overQty } else { return $stock_quantity };
```

it should work

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but it doesn't work. I get a blank screen, there must be something wrong with the code.

Comment: Simply returning a String variable won't show any output on the webpage to the end user

Comment: you could try echoing it out then instead of the return

Comment: @CorySpinney **Just for info:** on shortcode function, the data is never echoed but always returned, just like in filter hooks.